# Simple Array Integer Sum?

Tags: ruby

I have this array:

`array =  ["1", "Hel", "6", "3", "lo" ]` .

I want to output sum of the integers only, which is 10. How do I do that?

Answer (score 6):

just do :

```
array.inject(0) { |sum,n| sum + n.to_i } # => 10
```

`#to_i` will convert all the non integer strings to `0`. But there is no problem, as for that over all summation will not be affected.

Comment: Most process efficient so far. Benchmarked and this is faster than `array.map(&:to_i).reduce(0, :+)` (1.49s vs. 2.05s for 1000000 times for me)

Answer (score 5):

`String#to_i` will return `0` in your example so we can use it to map over all array elements.

```
array.map(&:to_i).reduce(0, :+)
```

Comment: Don't need to set initial for this problem, e.g. this produces same result: `array.map(&:to_i).reduce(:+)`. This is because initial defaults to the first item in the array, and even if to_i were to be called on a string or nil, both evaluate to 0, in Ruby 2.1 at least.

Comment: @GaryS.Weaver it's there to provide a robust solution: `[].reduce(:+) # nil` and `[].reduce(0, :+) # 0`

Comment: Good catch! You're right, that was probably the intent.

Answer (score 0):

Since Ruby 2.4 array has an [Enumerable#sum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sum) method.

```
array.sum(&:to_i)
```